# Динамическое изменение размера колонки в bootstrap4

Tags: bootstrap

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, есть менюшка которая отображается в зависимости от наличия прав у пользователя. Выглядит примерно вот так:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    if (Yii::$app->user->can('seeIt')) {
      echo "menu"
    }
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9">
    Another content
  </div>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что если менюшка не отрисовывается, то блок с `Another content` не будет равномерно размазан по экрану, а заёмет 9 колонок.

Я закостылил это следующим образом:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    $numOfCol = 12;
    if (Yii::$app->user->can('seeIt')) {
      echo "menu"
      $numOfCol = 9;
    }
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-<?=$numOfCol?>">
    Another content
  </div>
</div>
```

Но подозреваю, что это можно как то решить средствами самого bootstrap. Подскажите?

Answer (score 1):

А если просто поставить `.col`?

```css
.foo {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="foo">
        меню
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="foo">
        Another content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="foo">
        Another content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Правда я бы тогда в `.row` запрет переноса поставила бы:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-nowrap"> ... </div>
```